# terminal gets stuck after typing some command in the mongo container shell

Tags: mongodb, docker

In my mac, I just want to inspect into the shell of a mongo container created based on the mongo:3.5.8 from docker hub and play with it.

However, Although I can go into the mongo shell by running `sudo docker exec -t mongo-test mongo`, the terminal gets stuck and there is no response, after typing any command (such as `show dbs`) and hitting enter.

thanks. Any idea could be really helpful.

The screenshot:
[the terminal get stuck after typing some command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnO7J.png)
[environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXCQs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the interactive option "i" like `sudo docker exec -it mongo-test mongo`

You can see all the options here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/